# Torres de Hanoi en codigo scheme

Tags: python

Tengo este código python pero necesito pasarlo a código de scheme de doctor racket y no se como hacerlo si de pronto alguien sabe como hacerlo y echarme una manito

```py
def Hanoi (discos,TorreOrigen=1,TorreAuxiliar=2,TorreDestino=3):
    if discos==1:
        print (TorreOrigen,"a",TorreDestino)

    else:
        Hanoi(discos-1,TorreOrigen,TorreDestino,TorreAuxiliar)
        print(TorreOrigen,"a",TorreDestino)
        Hanoi (discos-1,TorreAuxiliar,TorreOrigen,TorreDestino)
    return

Hanoi(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo te faltaría poner los argumentos que faltan cuando llamas a la función Hanoi. La función tiene tres argumentos( número de discos, torre de origen, torre de destino), en tu código solo pones el número de discos. Un saludo